# negative correlation scale free network

Tags: matlab

how to generate a scale-free network in matlab using negative correlation, which means the largest degree node will choose the smallest degree node to connect. 
I am always stuck at how to find the smallest degree node.

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far? (as an edit in your question, **not** a comment)

Comment: Do you already have correlations between nodes? Do you already have degree measures and, if so, from what network do they come from? Do you need to construct your network with a preferential attachment approach?